# I'm trying to call event but my Visual Code say ("event is deprecated ts(6385)")

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I'm studying Javascript using Visual Code and every time a similar exercise that uses 'event' (the event shows in the code with the strikethrough like e̶v̶e̶n̶t̶) appears I can't complete it because of this annoying issue. In the description pop up a warning showing the issue ("event is deprecated ts(6385)"). I look out in the forums and stack over flow but I can not find any answer for this problem, only a few places says the lib dom and @deprecated, but I don't what to do.

Please, any way to help and learn to pass this problem out will be very useful.

```
function sayMyFirstName(element){
    alert("My First name is..." + element.value)

}

function sayMyLastName(){
    console.log(event)

}
```

Comment: Q: Out of curiosity: are you getting `event is deprecated ts(6385)` at the line you showed, "console.log(event)"?  Is there other, relevant code you're *NOT* showing us? Where is "event" declared?  Is the file suffix "js"?  Or ".ts"?  In any case - read my suggestions below.

Comment: @paulsm4 Is js. In my source code material where i am studying they say that "event is global and you can call him from whatever the reason." The code I showed above it's just an example. I'm think the problem is with gitignore, and I paste the /*tslint:disabled*/ in my files. The problem comes and goes, the tricks you said worked in one problem but not in other, I need to sleep and I'll say to you tomorrow.

Comment: If you need more info, look here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32533 and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event.  See my additional comments below.

Comment: Q: Is your question resolved?  Did the additional info help?  If your source materials tell you to use the global event object - it's probably time to look for updated source materials ;)

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you're getting [TypeScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions) validation for a simple JS project.  There are several things you can try:

- In your settings file (settings.json):

  `"typescript.validate.enable": false`

... OR ...

- In your .js source file(s):

  `/*tslint:disabled*/`

---

A separate issue is why you're getting the "deprecation" warning in the first place.  This is the reason:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event
>
> The read-only Window property event returns the Event which is
> currently being handled by the site's code. Outside the context of an
> event handler, the value is always undefined.
>
> You should avoid using this property in new code, and should instead
> use the Event passed into the event handler function. This property is
> not universally supported and even when supported introduces potential
> fragility to your code.

In other words, "event" should really be passed as an argument to a JS [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers).  You shouldn't be using the global object; you shouldn't *NEED* to use the global object.

Here are a few good tutorials:

- [Introduction to events (MDN.com)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)
- [JavaScript Events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp)

**Strong suggestion:**

If you're learning JavaScript, please make sure your study materials are up-to-date (*definitely* covering ES6!). This is a good book: [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617292850)

Comment: The first trick worked!
Thank you. This really help me.

I tried to upvote you, but i cant do this right now.

Comment: Interestingly, it isn't working for me. Most of my projects are TS so I only turned validation off for the "workspace" of this one particular PHP/JS/jQuery project I work on. I'm going to play with adding the folder to a workspace and see if that makes a difference. And search for more answers. Might be back with a new question though.

Comment: Now it worked. For those working with different types of projects, you may need to change your settings for just the Workspace, and then add your non-TS project to that Workspace.

Comment: @tim.rohrer: in general, "Warnings are Good".  Don't forget: the whole reason for inventing TS in the first place is to ensure better "Type safety".  So the first priority should always be to *heed* warnings - and correct the underlying problem - whenever possible.  "Gagging warnings" should be considered a "last resort".  In this case, it sounds like the OP was using some outdated tutorial that used the global "window.event" object; a practice which is now strongly *discouraged*.  I hope the OP heeds the warning ... and finds some new tutorials  :)

Comment: @paulsm4 I understand that TS warnings in a TS project make sense. In this case, a TS warning was being thrown for a jQuery call (`onClick`), claiming the method was deprecated when it isn't. I saw nothing indicating there was any validity.

Comment: Maybe the real topic to be discussed at this stage is why would VS Code's TS validator algorithm trigger in a javascript file (`.js`) without any Typescript in the project and without Typescript installed?

Answer (score 4):

You can use "window.event" to replace the deprecated "event".

Comment: The above perfectly replaces `d3.pointer(event, this)` with `d3.pointer(window.event, this)` in `d3.js`

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that the TypeScript Validator is saying the implicit passing of event is deprecated. A simple fix would be to pass the event into the function as a parameter

```
function sayMyLastName(event){
    console.log(event)
}
```

I'm migrating a lot of functionality from JS to Angular and found this issue a lot

Answer (score 0):

You just need to open `>Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)` by `Ctrl + Shift + P` in VSCode then add this line to JSON file `"editor.showDeprecated": false` to disable a show deprecated in case if you only need to some workspace.

If you want to disable all workspace then use `>Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` instead.

Comment: Disabling the deprecating warnings is not the right way. If we do this, we might end up using a lot of deprecated code, which eventually breaks in future.