# Why can't able to call the method directly from the template

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is my template and code:

```
const submit = (event: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
   console.log("submitted");
};
```

template:

```
<input type="password" defaultValue={repass} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} placeholder="userPassword Repeat" name="userPasswordRep" />
  <button disabled={isSubmit} onClick={submit(event)}>
    Sign Up{" "}
  </button>
```

here `handleChange` works. even the `button` works if I return using another function. but need know why can't we directly call the `submit` method from template, what is behind?

getting error and warnings:

> 'event' is deprecated.ts(6385)
> Unexpected use of 'event'.

Comment: Please search for warnings before asking questions. Read warnings, don't ignore them. And you should learn to recognize the difference between a warning and an error. [I'm trying to call event but my Visual Code say ("event is deprecated ts(6385)")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64585035/im-trying-to-call-event-but-my-visual-code-say-event-is-deprecated-ts6385)

Comment: Because that's not html its just javascript objects. for example, `<button>` is an object which has a key 'onClick' and a value `submit(event)`. value `submit(event)` means it get executed as soon as the object get defined.  You get `event'` is deprecated error because that event refer to global `event` object which is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call pass the event explicitly here

```
 <button disabled={isSubmit} onClick={submit}>
```

which is similar to this

```
<button disabled={isSubmit} onClick={() => submit(event)}>
```

Comment: Yes agree. My doubt is how all this works? how context changes and updates